# Dynamically Add\Remove columns SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS report that has around 80+ columns. I have requirement where in dynamically hide\show columns in report based on user selection. I could able to do it by setting expression for "Visiblity" property and having report parameter thro' which columns to display can be choosen.

My problem is 2 points

1. fox example if columns 2 and 4 to be hidden, then there is an empty column between 1 and 3 and 5 columns. How to avoid this
2. When i export to PDF / Excel these spaces prevail.

Let me know your suggestions / help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved my issue with following URL
http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/conditionally-setting-column-visibility-in-ssrs/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query that pivots your data, so that instead of a return table like this:

- **ColumnName0, ColumnName1, ColumnName2**
- Value[0][0], Value[0][1], Value[0][2]
- Value[1][0], Value[1][1], Value[1][2]

You could format it like this

- **ColumnName, Value0, Value2**
- ColumnName0, Value[0][0], Value[1][0]
- ColumnName1, Value[0][1], Value[1][1]
- ColumnName2, Value[0][2], Value[1][2]

And then your first column (ColumnName) would always be your title, and you could use it as your column group. You might have to use a dynamic query for this, but it would take care of both items 1 and 2 in your question.